# Partial Flag Varieties and Quotients of Symmetric Polynomials

Tags: quantum-groups, symmetric-functions, grassmannians, flag-varieties, categorification

$\def\Q{\mathbf Q}\DeclareMathOperator{\Gr}{Gr}$First, consider a Grassmannian $\Gr(k, N)$ of $k$-dimensional subspaces in an $N$-dimensional space. It is known that its cohomology ring is

$$H_k=\Q[c_1,\ldots, c_k, \bar c_1,\ldots,\bar c_{N-k}]$$

modulo the ideal generated by homogeneous parts of

$$(1+c_1t+c_2t^2+\ldots)(1+\bar c_1t + \bar c_2 t^2+\ldots +\bar c_{N-k}t^{N-k})-1.$$

Denote this description by **(A)**.

On the other hand, we can consider the quotient

$$H_k=\frac{\Q[e_1, \ldots, e_k]}{(h_i|i > N-k)},$$

where $e_i$ denotes the $i$-th elementary symmetric polynomial in $k$-variables, and $h_i$ denotes the $i$-th complete homogeneous symmetric polynomial, i.e.

$$\Q[e_1,\ldots, e_k]=\Q[x_1,\ldots, x_k]^{S_k}.$$

Call this description **(B)**. Developing the $h$ in terms of $e$ shows that indeed both descriptions of $H_k$ coincide, cf. https://arxiv.org/abs/1106.2128, §5, and the referenced equations.

### Passage to partial flag varieties

Now let us instead consider $\Gr(k, l, N)$, the variety of subspaces

$$\{V_k\subseteq V_l\subseteq V_N|\dim V_i=i\}.$$

It is known that its cohomology ring $H_{k,l}$ is

$$\Q[c_{11}, \ldots, c_{1k}, c_{2,1},\ldots, c_{2,l-k}, c_{3,1},\ldots, c_{3,N-l}]$$

modulo the ideal generated by homogeneous parts of

$$(1+c_{11}t+\ldots+c_{1k}t^k)(1+c_{2,1}t+\ldots+c_{2,l-k}t^{l-k})(1+c_{3,1}+\ldots+c_{3,N-l}t^{N-l})-1.$$

It admits inclusions from $H_k$ and $H_l$, coming from the map that forgets one subspace. This can be generalized for any sequence of increasing dimensions.

### My Question

In the case where we consider the Grassmannian for one subspace, we could find the alternative description **(B)** in terms of symmetric polynomials. Is there a description **(B)** for $H_{k,l,\ldots}$?